# Setting Default value when Object mapping in Red-Gate Data Compare

Tags: redgate, red-gate-data-compare

I am using [Red-Gate Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to synchronize two databases, lets call them **DBSource** and **DBDestination**.  DBDestination has a table, **TableA** which has a field which has a `not null` constraint.  TableA within DBSource has the same structure, apart from this new field.

When I synchronize using the *Data Compare tool*, it fails due to this particular `not null` field, since there's no object map I can set up for it.

I wanted to know if there is a way of setting a default on the tool, since I can't alter the schema of the destination table and the file is quite large to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to alter the column in the database and put a default value on it. There isn't anything you can do in the SQL Data Compare settings to make it replace illegal NULL data with a default value.

Comment: This is what I ended up with. I think I might email the Red-Gate support to ask for this feature to be added.

Comment: Uservoice would be more effective. https://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/147879-sql-data-compare

Comment: Already there, https://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/147879-sql-data-compare/suggestions/2973662-allow-copying-data-to-destination-that-may-have-no